# Html checkbox input jquery event not firing

Tags: css, asp.net, checkbox, styles

I am workingin asp.net c# for my own reasons i dicided to use an html control instead of asp.net control.

Here is the code for the checkbox i made, it has some css applied to it.

Why isn't the mouse down event firing?

here is the jsfiddle.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rubinoff/k6n8K/)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG1" id="checkboxG1" class="css-checkbox" />
<label for="checkboxG1" class="css-label">Checkbox</label>

$('#checkboxG1').mousedown(function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event like this:

```
 $('#checkboxG1').change(function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/7q8BN/1/)